# Insert a text selected via visual block

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode, visual-block

I'm facing a behavior that I find unatural when trying to paste a block of text selected with visual block mode (`<C-v>`): I can't insert it between two lines without messing with the already existing line.

Here's an example:

If I have this file

```
abc
def
hij
klm

This is a text
on several lines
and this is another line
```

Let's say I want to put the first letters of each of the 4 first lines between the 2 others lines of text.

- First I'll select the 4 letters: `<C-v> 3j y`
- Then I put my cursor on the `o` of the last line
- Finally I put my letters before my cursor with `P`

The result I get is:

```
This is a text
aon several lines
dand this is another line
g
j
```

Where as what I expected was

```
this is a text 
a
d
g
j
on several lines
and this is another line
```

So it means that each time I want to past a block this way I have to insert the corresponding number of empty lines before I past which is pretty unatural in my opinion.

I found a vim tip suggesting to use `1vp` to select a corresponding number of lines before pasting but that allows a replacement not an insertion of the block.

**So my question is:** What is the good way to insert a visually selecting block between two existing lines?

**Also** I once saw a plugin (which I can't remember the name) which "improved" visual block mode, but I'd like not to add a plugin just to enable this behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paste visual block selection on its own lines](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8878/paste-visual-block-selection-on-its-own-lines)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That plugin you're referring to might be my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355), which provides (among many related other commands) the exact `glp` (force linewise paste) command you're looking for here.

As its author, I surely think the plugin provides very helpful functionality that warrants installing it, but you can achieve the same via a simple built-in command. After yanking, execute:

```
:call setreg('', '', 'ac')
```

Then paste with `P`. This changes the *type* of the default register from blockwise to characterwise. (As there's no `setregtype()` function, it does this by appending (`a`) nothing (`''`) to the register.)

The `setreg()` approach also works for other such conversions (e.g. characterwise to linewise with `'al'` parameter.)

For your particular example, there's an even shorter (but less general) way:

```
:put!
```

will always paste in new lines.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tips (I'll also check your plugin)! Your answer leads me to another question (I don't know if I should create a new one or ask it here): let's say I want to map `P` to call `setreg()` and then put but only when I made a block selection is there a way to create such a mapping? I can't create it only in visual mode because it is not relevant and create it in normal mode would override `P` each time which is not what I want neither.

Comment: You can use `getregtype()` to check whether the register contains a blockwise selection. But in my opinion, blockwise paste can be useful, too, so I would recommend a separate mapping.

Comment: Yes I think you're right. Anyway I checked your plugin and I think I will simply use that it is the most convenient. Thanks again for your answers!

Answer (score 6):

You can get the behavior you want with: <kbd>O</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> in Insert mode pastes a register -- in this case, the default `"` register.  Since you're in Insert mode, it ignores the block-ness of the buffer.

Comment: Thats is a totally valid way to do it and I didn't know <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>. So thats a good answer thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [tpope/vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) also comes with some useful linewise paste mappings:

```
PASTING                                         *unimpaired-pasting*

These are experimental:

*>p*    Paste after linewise, increasing indent.
*>P*    Paste before linewise, increasing indent.
*<p*    Paste after linewise, decreasing indent.
*<P*    Paste before linewise, decreasing indent.
*=p*    Paste after linewise, reindenting.
*=P*    Paste before linewise, reindenting.

|]p|, |[p|, |[P|, and |]P| have also been remapped to force linewise pasting,
while preserving their usual indent matching behavior.

                                                *[op* *]op* *yop*
A toggle has not been provided for 'paste' because the typical use case of
wrapping of a solitary insertion is inefficient:  You toggle twice, but
you only paste once (YOPO).  Instead, press [op, ]op, or yop to invoke |O|,
|o|, or |0||C| with 'paste' already set.  Leaving insert mode sets 'nopaste'
automatically.
```

Comment: So I did forgot I asked this question *8 years ago* :D Despite the huge popularity of this unimpaired I never ended up installing it, for this specific use case I got the habit of using `ctrl+r "` but unimpaired seems like a good solution too