# Paste visual block selection on its own lines

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-block

I'm not really sure how to describe what I'd like to do. Basically I'd like to use visual block mode to select a region of text and then paste it "as a collection of lines" rather than as a rectangle.

```
a b
c d
e f
g h
```

after pressing `gg0<c-v>Gy` the rectangle `a/c/e/g` is in the default yank register (I forgot what it's called).

If I then paste the rectangle `p` I get the following:

```
aa b
cc d
ee f
gg h
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to paste a rectangle / visual block selection on a group of lines by itself, as if it were an ordinary visual selection.

```
a
c
e
g
a b
c d
e f
g h
```

Comment: You can set register type to linewise before pasting.  Something like this: `:call setreg('+', @+, 'V')`.  Depending on your OS and your setting of `clipboard`, you might need to do this for registers `*` or `"` instead.  It's longer to type than the answer below, but it might still come in handy in more complicated contexts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
:put! "
```

- `:put`: insert the contents of the specified register
- `!`: insert before the current line (the default is after)
- `"`: the unnamed register (check `:help registers` for details)

You could do it from insert mode as well: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>

Comment: Since the default is `"`, `:put!` works just as well.